# Clear way to compare propertychanges to object with database properties?

Tags: c#

Long story short, I have an object with multiple properties that's being modified somewhere I can't **reach**. When I get the object back, 1, 2, all or none of the properties could be changed. Is there a way I can quickly/securely/automatically check the object's properties whether it's current state is different from the last saved state (available in the database).

Currently I can only think of writing a method that does this by hand;

```
public List<String> ChangedProperties VerifyPropertyIntegrity(MyObject DatabaseObject, MyObject CurrentObject)
{
    var ChangedProperties = new List<String>();
    if (DatabaseObject.PropertyA != CurrentObject.PropertyA)
    {
        ChangedProperties.Add(DatabaseObject.PropertyA); //Let's assume it's a string
    }
    // And so further for all 15 properties
    return ChangedProperties;
}
```

And each if-cycle will only get bigger because it has to check the itemType of the property to be able to pass it all in 1 list back, to then parse it back to the original itemType once this method returns the list to the method it's been called by.

Any suggestions as to how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Create an event so far ?

Comment: @Buffer_z what .. ?

Comment: Yes, use a concurrency-check. In SQL Server you would add column of type **timestamp**. This gets updated automatically whenever you update the record, after which it is different from any old in-memory object.

Comment: I don't think there's another way.If you can't change the code that changes your object properties,i'm afraid you'll have to check the object properties by hand

Comment: @Maarten if I understand OP, the other part changing the object does not change anything in the database, just in an object passed to it

Comment: @Maarten going blindly on what I think you mean; I have a column that marks a timedate with last modified (by me) so I can determine IF an object had it's properties changed by another source (simply check it's modifiedAt to the modifiedAt in the DB), but then I need to know WHICH properties have been changed.

Comment: And I guess you can't change `MyObject`implementation Ciphra

Comment: why don't you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: @Pikoh exactly, and not completely. I do create a copy of the actual object that has been changed (after the changing), so depending on what you want to do there are posibilities..

Comment: Then, to my understanding, there's no other way that by hand. Sorry ;)

Comment: @Pikoh then in 2 weeks my boss will be asking why the program is running so slowly when checking for modifications :^).  Thanks for looking at it, I guess I'll start building then..

Comment: What i was thinking of is, in your `DatabaseObject` definition adding a field  to hold the changed properties, and in the setter of the methods update that field. But in your scenario I don't think it's possible

Comment: @Pikoh Nope, because the only data-base handling that is done with the object is on my part, and I can't write it in the parts I can't reach (otherwise I could see what is changed in the first place and the problem wouldn't exist :p).